# Will Portable Class Libraries for Windows Phone 8 support MEF?

Tags: mef, portable-class-library, windows-phone-8

Until now the [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do not support [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/). Will this change with Windows Phone 8 since it uses the same kernel as Windows 8? Is there official information about this I did not find yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, the only answer that can be given is "nothing has been officially announced regarding MEF on Windows Phone 8".

Perhaps, when the SDK for Windows Phone 8 devices gets released, or a press release makes a statement, a definitive answer can be given.

Answer (score 2):

The MEF library we produced over here is consumable in portable libraries targeting current and future platforms (4.5, Metro, +Future): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/05/30/mef-and-tpl-dataflow-nuget-packages-for-net-framework-4-5-rc.aspx.

Comment: And if MEF is consumable as a PCL , then it'll work on Windows Phone 8.